# Dynamically create multiple CronTriggerBean beans

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

How to dynamically create multiple **CronTriggerBean** beans.

My system currently uses a property file to get the times for running the job
For example: 
    SCHEDULE_TIME=09:30,10:55,17:35

Now, I will get these values and create cron expressions for them.

Now I want to create multiple **CronTriggerBean** beans with the cron expressions that I have with me.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="crontestJobTriggerTradeCheck"
    class="frameworkx.springframework.scheduling.quartz.InitializingCronTrigger">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <ref bean="tradeCheck" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

try to create class like InitializingCronTrigger extends CronTriggerFactoryBean .Set CronExpression in InitializingCronTrigger .